# Find maximum value from an ArrayList

Tags: arrays, arraylist, max, processing, processing.js

I created an ArrayList function signature to find all the maximum household incomes from year 1984 to 2016. Now I wanted to find the maximum value from that ArrayList.

I tried to use max() but it didn't work out. I also tried to use Collections.max as well.

```
//Data 
string [] year = {"1984"    ,   "1987"  ,   "1989"  ,   "1992"  ,   "1995"  ,   "1997"  
                    ,   "1999"  ,   "2002"  ,   "2004"  ,   "2007"  ,   "2009"  ,   
                    "2012"  ,   "2014"  ,   "2016"}; 

float [] [] HHI = {
    {1065.00    ,   690.00  ,   625.00  ,   1040.00 ,   1039.00 ,   960.00  ,   1183.00 ,   883.00  ,   692.00  ,   1590.00 ,   756.00  ,   1212.00 ,   1033.00 ,   1920.00},
    {1060.00    ,   718.00  ,   667.00  ,   1034.00 ,   908.00  ,   900.00  ,   1130.00 ,   863.00  ,   711.00  ,   1558.00 ,   694.00  ,   1116.00 ,   1141.00 ,   1790.00},
    {1150.00    ,   749.00  ,   712.00  ,   1084.00 ,   1083.00 ,   961.00  ,   1326.00 ,   973.00  ,   817.00  ,   1658.00 ,   759.00  ,   1264.00 ,   1190.00 ,   1824.00},
    {1713.00    ,   1048.00 ,   907.00  ,   1459.00 ,   1380.00 ,   1262.00 ,   1821.00 ,   1274.00 ,   1040.00 ,   2280.00 ,   939.00  ,   1490.00 ,   1480.00 ,   2429.00},
    {2137.71    ,   1295.42 ,   1090.80 ,   1843.21 ,   1766.66 ,   1435.73 ,   2224.63 ,   1436.11 ,   1157.94 ,   3161.68 ,   1116.97 ,   1646.69 ,   1885.97 ,   3371.01},
    {2772.00    ,   1590.00 ,   1249.00 ,   2276.00 ,   2378.00 ,   1632.00 ,   3130.00 ,   1940.00 ,   1507.00 ,   4006.00 ,   1497.00 ,   2057.43 ,   2241.78 ,   4768.00},
    {2645.57    ,   1612.00 ,   1314.00 ,   2260.00 ,   2335.00 ,   1482.00 ,   3128.00 ,   1743.00 ,   1431.00 ,   3702.48 ,   1599.00 ,   1905.00 ,   2275.89 ,   4104.61},
    {2963.00    ,   1966.00 ,   1674.00 ,   2650.00 ,   2739.00 ,   1991.00 ,   3496.00 ,   2153.00 ,   2006.00 ,   4406.00 ,   1837.00 ,   2406.32 ,   2515.00 ,   4930.00},
    {3076.00    ,   2126.00 ,   1829.00 ,   2791.00 ,   2886.00 ,   2410.00 ,   3531.00 ,   2207.00 ,   2046.00 ,   5175.00 ,   1984.00 ,   2487.00 ,   2725.00 ,   5011.00},
    {3456.63    ,   2407.79 ,   2142.81 ,   3421.30 ,   3336.20 ,   2994.68 ,   4003.73 ,   2545.07 ,   2540.67 ,   5579.88 ,   2463.48 ,   2837.00 ,   3349.01 ,   5322.00},
    {3835.00    ,   2667.00 ,   2536.00 ,   4184.00 ,   3540.00 ,   3279.00 ,   4407.00 ,   2809.00 ,   2617.00 ,   5962.00 ,   3017.00 ,   3102.00 ,   3581.00 ,   5488.00},
    {4658.00    ,   3425.00 ,   3168.00 ,   4759.00 ,   4576.00 ,   3745.00 ,   5055.00 ,   3548.00 ,   3538.00 ,   7023.00 ,   3967.00 ,   4013.00 ,   4293.00 ,   8586.00},
    {6207.00    ,   4478.00 ,   3715.00 ,   6046.00 ,   5271.00 ,   4343.00 ,   5993.00 ,   4268.00 ,   4445.00 ,   8252.00 ,   4816.00 ,   4879.00 ,   4934.00 ,   10629.00},
    {6928.00    ,   4971.00 ,   4214.00 ,   6849.00 ,   5887.00 ,   5012.00 ,   6771.00 ,   5065.00 ,   4998.00 ,   9463.00 ,   5776.00 ,   5354.00 ,   5387.00 ,   11692.00}
};

//Function max 

ArrayList <Int> Max (float [][] data, string [] time){
    ArrayList <Int> maximum = new ArrayList <Int> ();
    for(i=0; i<time.length; i++){
        maximum.add(max(data[i]));
    }
    return maximum;
}

ArrayList <Int> MaxHHI=Max(HHI, year);
```

Is there anyway to get the maximum value from the ArrayList  MaxHHI ? 
Appreciate the help. Thanks a million.

Comment: Please try to be more specific: what exactly do you mean when you say you tried to use `max()` but it didn't work out?

Comment: Short answer "yes, there is one", but of course, we're running into the part where (inconveniently for you, but important for good questions that help other people, too) you're expected to first [search and research](/help/how-to-ask) your question yourself. This is not really a Processing or Processing.js question, but an algorithm question, so: do a web search on finding the the maximum value in a 1D, 2D, etc. array. On a sidenote: processing.js was discontinued in December of 2018.